# from google.colab import auth in Colab doesn't work with Google Workspace accounts

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, google-authentication, google-workspace

I'm trying to use Colab to connect to a bucket in my Google Cloud account. I'm running into this issue and was hoping for some direction on how to get around this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I'm going to regret this setting at some point in the future but I was able to get this working using this attached screenshot setting.

[image]